# How to change param order in URL of Kaminari pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

Right now I have a rails app where users can query for items. The url looks like

`localhost:3000/items?query=test&type=active`

However, Kaminari's pagination changes the param order:

`localhost:3000/items?type=active&page=2&query=test`

How do I change it to be:

`localhost:3000/items?query=test&type=active&page=2`

EDIT: I want to change this purely for aesthetic purposes. I just wanted the `page` param to be inserted after the existing params, without reversing their order and inserting itself in between.

Comment: Why do you want the params to be reordered? If you are referring to a param anywhere based on its position, then thats a wrong approach. You should always access params by name(key). Otherwise you will have to recreate the url in javascript. thats not encouraged.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ManjunathP I'm not referring to it anywhere, it just looks bad, which I know isn't a major concern. I just don't know why the params not only get reordered, but the page param is also inserted between the others. Odd.